# Deployment Error: Function deployment failed due to a health check failure on Google Cloud Function with Tweepy

Tags: python, google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions, tweepy

I am trying to pull twitter streaming data in cloud function and essentially export the stream data into big query.

Currently, i have this code. The **Entry Point** is set to `stream_twitter`.

main.txt:
import os
import tweepy
import pandas as pd
import datalab.bigquery as bq
from google.cloud import bigquery

```
import os
import tweepy
import pandas as pd
import datalab.bigquery as bq
from google.cloud import bigquery

#access key
api_key = os.environ['API_KEY']
secret_key = os.environ['SECRET_KEY']
bearer_token = os.environ['BEARER_TOKEN']

def stream_twitter(event, context):
  #authentication
  auth = tweepy.Client(bearer_token = bearer_token)
  api = tweepy.API(auth)

  #create Stream Listener
  class Listener(tweepy.StreamingClient):
    #save list to dataframe
    tweets = []
    
    def on_tweet(self, tweet):
      if tweet.referenced_tweets == None: #Original tweet not reply or retweet
        self.tweets.append(tweet)

    def on_error(self, status_code):
        if status_code == 420:
            #returning False in on_data disconnects the stream
            return False

  stream_tweet = Listener(bearer_token)

  #filtered Stream using rules
  rule = tweepy.StreamRule("(covid OR covid19 OR coronavirus OR pandemic OR #covid19 OR #covid) lang:en")
  stream_tweet.add_rules(rule, dry_run = True)
  stream_tweet.filter(tweet_fields=["referenced_tweets"])

  #insert into dataframe
  columns = ["UserID", "Tweets"]
  data = []

  for tweet in stream_tweet.tweets:
      data.append([tweet.id, tweet.text, ])

  stream_df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)

  ## Insert time col - TimeStamp to give the time that data is pulled from API
  stream_df.insert(0, 'TimeStamp', pd.to_datetime('now').replace(microsecond=0))
  ## Converting UTC Time to SGT(UTC+8hours)
  stream_df.insert(1,'SGT_TimeStamp', '')
  stream_df['SGT_TimeStamp'] = stream_df['TimeStamp'] + pd.Timedelta(hours=8)

  ## Define BQ dataset & table names
  bigquery_dataset_name = 'streaming_dataset'
  bigquery_table_name = 'streaming-table'

  ## Define BigQuery dataset & table
  dataset = bq.Dataset(bigquery_dataset_name)
  table = bq.Table(bigquery_dataset_name + '.' + bigquery_table_name)

  if not table.exists():
      # Create or overwrite the existing table if it exists
      table_schema = bq.Schema.from_dataframe(stream_df)
      table.create(schema = table_schema, overwrite = False)

  # Write the DataFrame to a BigQuery table
  table.insert_data(stream_df)
```

requirement.txt:

```
tweepy
pandas
google-cloud-bigquery
```

However, i keep getting a

**"Deployment failure: Function deployment failed due to a health check failure. This usually indicates that your code was built successfully but failed during a test execution. Examine the logs to determine the cause. Try deploying again in a few minutes if it appears to be transient."**

I can't seem to figure how to solve this error. Is there something wrong with my codes? Or is there something that i should have done? I test the streaming codes on Pycharm and was able to pull the data.

Would appreicate any help i can get. Thank you.

The logs to the function are this. (I am unfamiliar with Logs hence i shall include a screenshot.) Essentially, those were the 2 info and error i've been getting.

[image]

Comment: Edit your question and include the logs.

Comment: @JohnHanley I have editted the question. I am not sure if that is what you mean by the logs.

Comment: Yes, but show the part that has the error.

Comment: @JohnHanley the repeated error shown in the log seems to be the error above in the sreenshot. However, i did receive, 'ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'datalab' '

Comment: Can you check if `datalab` is installed by entering `pip install datalab`?

Comment: @RobertG yeap it is successfully installed. However 'ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'datalab'' still persist.

Comment: I realised that my indentation was wrong. The codes following the Listener Class was indented in Class as well. I have updates it to be indented under the stream_twitter function instead. Doing so, it raises 'Deployment failure:
Function failed on loading user code. This is likely due to a bug in the user code.' Apart from that, ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'datalab'' still persist.

Comment: Can you check this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/datalab-migration) that I found as `datalab==1.2.0` is added inside `requirements.txt`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to replicate your error message. All I did was add `datalab==1.2.0` inside `requirements.txt`. Since you are importing the `datalab` library, you need to include the support package for it, which is the latest version of [`datalab`](https://pypi.org/project/datalab/).

Here's the reference that I used: [Migrating from the datalab Python package](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/datalab-migration).

> See the [requirements.txt file](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/tree/master/bigquery/datalab-migration/requirements.txt) to view the versions of the libraries used for these code snippets.

Here's the screenshot of the logs:
[image]

Comment: This works! I am no longer facing 'ModuleError'. Rather now, 'Stream encountered HTTP error: 429'. But thank you for the help!